# How to create a drop down populated with previous four weeks in php

Tags: php, date

How to create a drop down navigation of the current week and previous weeks up to four in php. 
 [image]

```
$date = '04/24/20012';
$ts = strtotime($date);
$year = date('o', $ts);
$week = date('W', $ts);
for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {    
    $ts = strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$i);
    print date("m/d/Y l", $ts) . "\n";
}
```

This code populate the drop down with current week but what i want is to populate the drop down with previous four weeks.

Comment: $date = '04/24/20012';
$ts = strtotime($date);
$year = date('o', $ts);
$week = date('W', $ts);
for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {    
    $ts = strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$i);
    print date("m/d/Y l", $ts) . "\n";
}

Comment: this brings me the current week but what I want is to have list of preivous four weeks.

Comment: Tariq, add code to your question. Not comments. Its difficult to read and people simply will pass your question by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++)
{
    $weeks[] = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("-$i week", time()));
}
```

Gives:

```
array
  0 => string '04/23/2012' (length=10)
  1 => string '04/16/2012' (length=10)
  2 => string '04/09/2012' (length=10)
  3 => string '04/02/2012' (length=10)
  4 => string '03/26/2012' (length=10)
```

**EDIT:** If you want the range then do this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++)
{
    $k = $i - 1;
    $weeks[] = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("-$i week")) . ' - ' .
               date('m/d/Y', strtotime("-$k week -1 day"));
}
```

Gives:

```
array
  0 => string '04/23/2012 - 04/29/2012' (length=23)
  1 => string '04/16/2012 - 04/22/2012' (length=23)
  2 => string '04/09/2012 - 04/15/2012' (length=23)
  3 => string '04/02/2012 - 04/08/2012' (length=23)
  4 => string '03/26/2012 - 04/01/2012' (length=23)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start your week on Monday (and end on Friday) you can do something like this:

```
$this_monday = strtotime('monday this week');
for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++)
{
    $k = $i - 1;
    $weeks[] = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("-$i week", $this_monday)) . ' - ' .
               date('m/d/Y', strtotime("-$k week -3 day", $this_monday));
}
```